# using PowerShell Compare line with next line in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, comparison

How to compare the line with next line and delete the duplicate. If the record before is different. (i.e. the column B change)

When condition happen the line will be kept, if the line and next line are same will be deleted.  It's not checking for duplicate, is every line compare with next line.

For example original CSV

```
COLUMN A    COLUMN B   
--------    --------    
1           A        
2           A    
3           B    
4           C
5           C
6           A
```

Expected result is:

```
COLUMN A    COLUMN B   
--------    --------    
1           A         
3           B      
4           C        
6           A
```

Comment: Welcome. Give it a go, ask when you have a **specific** problem. [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer creating new collection for output:

```
$in = import-csv "test.csv"
$out = @()

foreach($a in $in) {
    if($a.ColumnB -ne $out[-1].ColumnB) {
        $out += $a
    }
}

$out
```